# Can I use pivotal table to create a heatmap table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have this data frame and the result dataframe:

```
df=  pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "I": ["I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7"],
        "A": [1,     1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        "B": [0,     1,    1,    0,    0,    1,    1],
        "C": [0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1],
        "D": [1,     1,    1,    1,    1,    0,    1],
        "E": [1,     0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    1],
        "F": [0,     0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0],
        "G": [0,     0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0],
        "H": [1,     1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1],
    })

result=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "I": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
        "A": [2,   1,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,   2],
        "B": [1,   4,   2,   3,   1,   0,   0,   3],
        "C": [0,   2,   2,   1,   1,   0,   0,   2],
        "D": [2,   3,   1,   6,   4,   2,   1,   3],
        "E": [1,   1,   1,   4,   4,   2,   1,   2],
        "F": [0,   0,   0,   2,   2,   2,   1,   0],
        "G": [0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0],
        "H": [2,   3,   2,   3,   2,   0,   0,   4],
    })

print('input dataframe')
print(df)
print('result dataframe')
print(result)
```

The result data frame is a square data frame (the number of rows and columns are the same), and the value in each cell is the number of rows with 1 on both columns.

for example the cell at A:B is the number of columns with 1 in Column A and 1 in column B. In this case, the result is 1 since only on row I2 the values for both columns are one.

I can write nested for loop to calculate these values, but I am looking for a better way to do so.
Can I use a pivotal table for this?

My implementation which doesn't use a pivot table is as follows:

```
df=df.astype(bool)
r=pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns[1:], columns=df.columns[1:])
for c1 in df.columns[1:]:
    for c2 in df.columns[1:]:
        tmp=df[c1] & df[c2]
        r.loc[c1][c2]=tmp.sum()
       
print(r)
```

running this code generates:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
A  2  1  0  2  1  0  0  2
B  1  4  2  3  1  0  0  3
C  0  2  2  1  1  0  0  2
D  2  3  1  6  4  2  1  3
E  1  1  1  4  4  2  1  2
F  0  0  0  2  2  2  1  0
G  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
H  2  3  2  3  2  0  0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'd be better off with matrix multiplication:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].T @ df.iloc[:,1:]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
A  2  1  0  2  1  0  0  2
B  1  4  2  3  1  0  0  3
C  0  2  2  1  1  0  0  2
D  2  3  1  6  4  2  1  3
E  1  1  1  4  4  2  1  2
F  0  0  0  2  2  2  1  0
G  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
H  2  3  2  3  2  0  0  4
```